# How do you get AWT graphics to appear on Window open?

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

I want to be able to have a window listener that when the window is opened, some graphics appear. This comes with some problem though, because you can't set a window listener while the window is set to visible (or at least that's what I've found), but if you wait to set the window to visible until after you set the listener you can't set the Graphics.

This is the code with the window set to visible at the start:

```
public class FrameTest {

    static Frame myFrame;
    static Graphics myGraphics;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Initializing Window
        myFrame = new Frame();
        myFrame.setTitle("Frame Test");
        myFrame.setSize(570, 570);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myGraphics = myFrame.getGraphics();
        myFrame.requestFocus();

        //Close Button
        myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("opened");
                myGraphics.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Start by not doing `myGraphics = myFrame.getGraphics();`.  This is a bad idea on so many levels. You should start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).  Also remember, overriding paint of a top level container like `Frame` is a bad idea and something you should avoid

Comment: Now, having said that, have you simply tried call `setBackground`?

Comment: Alright I'll look into that thanks

Comment: setBackground works

Comment: As I'm starting to look into those links I'm starting to see how unorthodox my coding is, I think if I follow those it will probably solve my problems, thanks.